# Turning screen off with Google Navigation

Tags: android, navigation

I would to know if I can programmatically turn the screen off when Google Navigation is open.

I've made a Wear app, which launches Google Navigation on the phone, but the screen stays on. The same *feature* happens when I launch Google Navigation by myself.

So can I force the system to turn the screen off after a delay, without my app being admin?

Edit:
I've use this :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But this only turn the dim to its minimum, not really turning the screen off
And I think this function work only for our activity, in my case, the last activity on screen is the Google Navigation activity's.

Thanks ;)